# Balls with replacement

Tags: probability

I have a simple question on drawing balls with replacement.

There are 20 red balls, and 10 blue balls, and it is interest in the event that {BBR} where order doesn't matter.

So P(BBR)=10/30*10/30*20/30.    Now, does the event {BBR} consist of: drawingBBR +drawingBRB+drawing RBB (these draws are with order), or do they not include?

If they included, then P(BBR)=3*(10/30)*(10/30)*(20/30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right with your answer.

Since the probabilities of the events are independent of each other the result is product of each probabilities of the events.

Comment: So, do you need to multipled by 3 (which coresponding to RRB,RBR,BRR), or you don't?

Comment: Since the events can be in any order the resultant probability is the sum of the events RRB, RBR, BRR. Each has the same probabilities so the result is 3 times the probability of any of the individual event.